# How can I view more posts per page?

Tags: support, user-interface

From what I know, we can only view 15/30/50 questions per page, or 30 answers per page.

I'm wondering if there is a way to load more posts in a page. If yes, how can I do it?

I tried to modify this URL,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=newest&pagesize=50
```

and increase the `pagesize=50` to a higher number like `pagesize=100`, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't think there's a way since 50 seems to be the hard limit that the SO dev allows.

Comment: @AndrewT. It doesn't have to be a stackoverflow feature tho, perhaps there is some chrome extensions or anything like that which could do it?

Comment: This seems like an upper limit which is set probably to keep the costs of requests down... if that is true it wouldn't exactly be a nice thing to try and circumvent it anyway.

Comment: You can fetch 100 result via api . https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=100&order=desc&tagged=javascript&site=stackoverflow

Comment: [50,000](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1435229)  but only the questions up to last Sunday

Comment: [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) .